# Is my computer safe after accessing .onion sites without VPN?

Tags: network, vpn, tor

After watching a youtube video about .onion sites and I got Tor and just went on one without clicking any of the links. Then I got off Tor and that was pretty much it.

But I've read an article about information being leaked without a VPN. Is my computer in danger now?

Comment: It all depends on what you're actually doing.

Comment: This question translates basically to: "I went outside to somewhere and then I got back. I wonder if I'm sick now or maybe in some days."

Answer (score 0):

If your computer was attacked by the .onion site, it would be attacked through a browser exploit.  Browser exploits do not care about how the traffic arrives at your computer, only that it does.  They will work over TOR, over a VPN, or over a direct connection.  Accessing a .onion site is not (by itself) any riskier than any other website you've never visited before.  (In fact, visiting a .onion site over TOR may be safer than visiting a non-.onion site over TOR, as you don't have the problem of malicious exit nodes.)